# Incrementally add date with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a variable $scope.date in my controller. In the view, I do ng-repeat over a couple of items. Each item has a duration in minutes. How would I go about to incrementally add time for every repeat and display this?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function on the controller that calculates the date including the duration. Working code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.someDate = new Date();
  $scope.durations = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8];

  $scope.calculateIncrementalDuration = function(index) {

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
      sum += $scope.durations[i];
    }
    return sum;
  }
  $scope.calculateEndDate = function(startDate, index) {
    return new Date(startDate.getTime() + $scope.calculateIncrementalDuration(index) * 60000);
  }
});
```

```css
.delay {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  Start time: {{someDate.toUTCString()}}
  <div class="delay" ng-repeat="duration in durations">Duration in minutes: {{calculateIncrementalDuration($index)}}
    <div>End time: {{calculateEndDate(someDate, $index).toUTCString()}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear, but I meant to incrementally add the delay. That is, the first delay being 1, the second 3, the third 8 and so on. I suppose I could loop through the array in the controller, but I was thinking about incrementally adding in the ng-repeat.

Comment: updated answer to calculate the incremental duration

Comment: you can use $index within ng-repeat, this will give you the index of the item. That way, it is pretty easy to calculate the dates within the controller

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation for a comment, so please don't be angry at me, those who get angry at non-answers as answers, but I would highly recommend looking into [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) for things like this.